# How do I resize/change resolution of pictures easily?

Tags: images

I just tried to make a post on another StackExchange site, but unfortunately, when I tried to take a picture of the problem, I got an error that the image must be less than 2 MB to upload it to StackExchange! The edit button on my Android photos app lets me draw over, crop, change tint/brightness/contrast, and add lots of WACKY EFFECTS to my pictures, but I can't figure out how to shrink the resolution! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any "native" or "pre-installed" capabilities. But the easiest way, if you need it more than once a year, is to use a suitable app. You can find some candidates in my app-listing [Other photo editors](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/foto_edit#group_222). Examples:

- [JustResizeIt!](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.perspectives.jrifree) allows to resize single images or entire batches. Comes for free, size less than 1MB, decent permissions (access storage and internet only).
- [Image Shrink Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gmail.anolivetree.imageshrinklite) is even smaller (less than 400k), and additionally allows you to remove Exif data (location etc.) No network permissions requested, just read/write storage. Free again.

Both mentioned apps also have paid counterparts; I didn't check the differences between those versions. For more candidates, see the list linked above :)

Comment: The 2nd one works really easily, thanks! I can just select upload from Image Shrink Lite, then select the image, then it uploads the shrinked version right away! Awesome!

Comment: I can recommend my app [Resize image](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=get.the.solution.Image.XF.Droid), free, no size limit, decent permission requests and share capability.

Answer (score 1):

Easey peasy. Search online for resize tools.
I'll give you a random one...

http://www.picresize.com/

Upload your image and select the resolution you want to get.

Comment: That requires to upload the picture twice: full resolution (to the resizer), reduced resolution (to SE). Plus downloading the reduced resolution from that site. Needs to be considered concerning bandwidth and data plan :)

Comment: @Izzy Well another solution would be to download one of the android apps who handles this type of problems :)
On other hand, it also needs bandwidth and data to download the app.
So, it's up to user on which side he wants to lose or gain :)
Online - flexibility, use when you need, also takes data.
App - fast/reliable, but takes space on device.

Comment: You download the app once. See my answer: 400k, one time only. Already bandwidth saved on the first image resized from 2M to 500k :)

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure if this is the right thing for you but from time to time i use [Send Reduced](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=mobi.omegacentauri.SendReduced):

once you have done your settings in the app, you can resize images by just using the share button and "share it via"/"send it to" Send Reduced. no extra interface, settings or other junk you have to consider... just resizing.

[image: share picture via]

it is very handy if you use the same resolution for the most of the pictures you want to resize, and also for batch-resizing it is quick and easy.